# How is this recursive

Tags: javascript

How is this recursive(repeating over and over)?

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
// → 8
```

Comment: "Recursive" doesn't mean "repeating over and over". It means it calls itself, but (hopefully) with some terminating condition that allows it eventually to return back. This function is "recursive": it calls itself as long as `exponent` is not `0`. It will probably  will stack-overflow if you call `power(base, exp)` with a negative `exp` since it will take a very large number of recursive calls before `exponent == 0` to be true in that case.

Comment: @CasperBeyer Does it ring a bell if it's homework or not? It's still vague ... judging by its title.

Answer (score 1):

The function calls itself, thus it is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is "the process of repeating items in a self-similar way".

Imagine if you will that you are at the hairdresser or barbershop looking into the mirror in front of you, in the mirror you see a reflection of yourself, as-well as the other side of the room which also has a mirror, and in the mirror on the other side you see yourself looking into the mirror on the other side, looking into the mirror on the other side, and so on, indefinitely.

So put simply, your function is recursive because it calls itself until `exponent` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating something over and over is not recursion, that is iteration. The function is recursive because it's calling itself.

However, that is a pretty bad example of recursion. It's basically just a loop written to use recursion instead, which performs badly and uses a lot of stack space.

A better way to show how recursion is used properly it to split the work in half, and use one recursive call to solve each of the halves:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    var n = Math.floor(exponent / 2);
    return power(base, n) * power(base, exponent - n);
  }
}
```

When called with an exponent of for example 100, this will do recursive calls to a depth of 7, instead of to a depth of 100.